# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Why it consider string as function

Tags: r

I have the variable `PA_coltypes` given by this command.

```
> PA_coltypes <- pa.get_coltypes(PA)
```

Now, if you want to see its contains here :

```
> PA_coltypes
                                    coltypes
1                CD_TY_TT  = col_character()
2  DA_TT  = col_date(format='%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
3                   A_ARR  = col_character()
4                   M_ARR  = col_character()
5                  CD_ETS  = col_character()
6                   CD_SI  = col_character()
7                  CD_EFS  = col_character()
8             IDT_ETT_CTR  = col_character()
9             NO_PCI_RCCL  = col_character()
10             CD_DVS_ORI  = col_character()
11              CD_NOR_CG  = col_character()
12                  CD_BT  = col_character()
13             NO_STR_CPB  = col_character()
14             NO_STR_RPQ  = col_character()
15             CD_LET_CPT  = col_character()
16                    MT_DVS  = col_double()
17                    MT_EUR  = col_double()
18         NO_CTR_MTR_FUS  = col_character()
19                CD_PCEC  = col_character()
20         CD_CRV_CIA_ORI  = col_character()
21             CD_TY_PCEC  = col_character()
```

Then when I want to evaluate this expression like this :

```
> eval(parse(text=paste("cols (",toString(PA_coltypes$coltypes),")")))
```

This error was shown

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "cols"

It say that `cols` is a function which is wrong.

How resolve this error please ?

Comment: the error actually says that `cols` is not a known function so both of you seem to agree on that.

Comment: `sapply(PA, typeof)` ?

Answer (score 0):

#### From [eval docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html):

> eval evaluates the expr argument in the environment specified by envir
>   and returns the computed value. If envir is not specified, then the
>   default is parent.frame() (the environment where the call to eval was
>   made).

`parse` returns the expression `expression(cols (...`, which `eval` tries to evaluate. If R sees `cols(args)`, it looks like a function so R tries to find it, and it can't, and it throws an error.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but what should I do to correct it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to extract columns's types : `character` or `double`

Comment: @lmed just do `sapply(PA, typeof)`

Comment: @Cath, I have no variable names 'typeof' !

Comment: ```typeof``` is a function that will give you the column types you're looking for